# Visual Basic OpenLinks Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Using the following code to open a bunch of links in column A of my doc, looking to have it wait 3sec after opening the link and then moving onto the next but instead of opening a new window or tab I want it to simply use the window already open.

```
Sub OpenLinks()

For Each vCell In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate (vCell.Value)
Next vCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Please remember to mark your questions as solved if you get a suitable answer.  It appears you may have neglected to do so in the past.  Marking your questions as solved prevents other developers working on your question when it is already solved.  It also helps other searching with a similar problem get the answer faster.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub OpenLinks()

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

For Each vCell In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    oIE.Visible = True
    oIE.Navigate (vCell.Value)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
Next vCell

End Sub
```

But, as always I recommend you consider using With/End With instead of Set.

```
Sub OpenLinks()  

With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

For Each vCell In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate (vCell.Value)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
Next vCell

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try, I got the code from elsewhere so not really sure how I would use     With/Endwith

Comment: No worries, see my edited answer regarding on how to use with.

Comment: Got it! --- anyway to also get this to work on OSX with office 2011?

Comment: That will require mac script, I suggest you start another question for porting the script to mac.